# Python Notes.py error on command

Tags: python

I'm trying to use the following code (http://bpaste.net/show/146050):

```
if used_prefix and cmd == "rn" and self.getAccess(user) >=1:
    try:
      if notes.check(user.name) == True:
        for l in notes.one(user.name):
           for sender, message, rawtime in l:
              room.message("Note from %s: %s [%s] " % sender, message, self.LongTimeStampFull(rawtime))
      else:
        room.message("Your inbox is empty.")
    except:
      room.message((str(sys.exc_info()[1])))
```

When I run it, it gives an error saying it needs more than 1 value to unpack on for sender, message, rawtime in l: Oh L should = ['sender', 'message', rawtime]

How do I fix this?

Comment: Too many items to unpack means your list is longer than you think it is.  IE:  `a, b = (1,2,3)`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your list contains just 3 items, so a loop is not required there. Just do:

```
>>> lis = ['sender', 'message', 'rawtime']
>>> sender, message, rawtime = lis
>>> sender
'sender'
>>> message
'message'
>>> rawtime
'rawtime'
```

If you want to use a for-loop then use a list of lists or list of tuples:

```
>>> lis = [('sender', 'message', 'rawtime')]
>>> for x, y, z in lis:
...     print x, y, z
...     
sender message rawtime
```

**Update:** Fixed version of your code:

```
for sender, message, rawtime in notes.one(user.name):
        room.message("Note from %s: %s [%s] " % sender, message, self.LongTimeStampFull(rawtime))
```

Comment: So just do notes.one(user.name) = [('sender', 'message', 'rawtime')] notes.one(user.name) retrieves the list ftom the database

Comment: It didn't work lol. It gave 'too many values to unpack(expected 3)

Comment: @user2950638 What does `notes.one(user.name)` returns?